# How to construct a 64K x 8 memory chip using 16K x 1 memory chips?

Tags: memory

I am trying to construct a 64K x 8 bit memory chip in Logisim using 16K x 1 chips. I am trying to figure out how many chips I need, and how the select lines and memory banks should be organized.

I know I can use 8 of the 16K x 1 chips to create a 16K x 8 chip. My initial thought is that I would have 4 memory banks each containing 8 of the 16K x 1 chips, for a total of 32 chips. Is that correct?

I know a 64K x 1 chip would need 16 select lines; how would that change in a 64K x 8 chip?

I don't know if I am asking the right questions here. The only examples I have use a decoder to select a memory bank, and then the least significant address lines to select the location within each chip, but they are for much smaller systems.

Any advice or hints to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware design (even if it is using a software simulator). Ask on [electronics.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YEs, you will need 32 chips. For those chips you connect 4 output bits to the same bit in the bus (i.e. 4 x 8). The only extra thing you need is a decoder for the two highest address bits. This is a 2-to-4 decoder which is then connected to the chip enable of the four banks of your memory.

Usually the memory chips have both the address lines (14 in the case of 16kx1 chips) plus at least one CE (chip enable line). You will connect the same 14 lowest address line bits to the chips as address lines.

Just make sure your decoding logic only enables one chip bank at a time.

(BTW, if you have difficulties routing the address lines, you may rearrange them any way you want, as long as they are in the same order at each memory chip.)

Answer (score 0):

A 16kX1 has 14 address lines. So the 16 bit input's first 14 will be the address of the all 32 16kX1 chips and for the rest 2 bit, use a 2to 4 decoder to connect them with the chips. there will be 4 rows and each row will have 8 chips.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E09Qh.jpg  ....click here to see the figure